# How to install xadmin for django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I installed the xadmin app to django now how do i call it or implement it for my admin module.what changes have to made in the setting.py and admin.py file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add xadmin application into the settings:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
...
    'xadmin',
...
)
```

Also you need to enable xadmin as you do for django's admin in the urls.py:

```
# urls.py
...
import xadmin
xadmin.autodiscover()
...
urlpatterns = patterns('',
...
```

And **important** notice: your file with models registration should be named adminx.py, not admin.py. Django's admin is little bit incompatible with xadmin (because xadmin has alot of custom implementation and metaclasses).
But for the common case it's done by the same way (except base class is object, because xadmin automatically extends it by plugins), i.e.:

```
# adminx.py
import xadmin
from . import models

class ProductAdmin(object):
    list_display = ['name', 'address', 'position']

class ReviewAdmin(object):
    list_display = ['created', 'owner', 'text']

xadmin.site.register(models.ProductInfo, ProductAdmin)
xadmin.site.register(models.Review, ReviewAdmin)
```

I've made very tricky hack for **automatic** merging base django admin's descriptions into the xadmin registry. If you are interested in I could share it.

**Updated**: my gist with [such merger](https://gist.github.com/IMDagger/9220764)

Comment: sure whats the tricky hack for automatic merging base django admin's descriptions into the xadmin registry.

Comment: sorry for the late response, this [gist](https://gist.github.com/IMDagger/9220764) contains solution (with a small howto) that I used, it's not checked for all cases, but works for all my libraries' admins.

Comment: @IMdagger...the django xdmin currently supports only exporting data via excel..it does not support importing data..there is a reusaable django  app called django import export which can be easily integrated with the conventional django admin..How do i use this with xadmin ..

Comment: i've never used django-import-export, but you can try to add the code from my gist and activate xadmin application (instead of admin), and may be it will work (but i'm not sure). Nothing special is needed, just "merging code" which registers admin's models into the xadmin space. But for some reasons it doesn't work, because it's a hack and doesn't cover all cases.

Comment: None of this worked for me. The fact that xadmin has no documentation and even then still seems to require some non-trivial rewriting of your modeladmins means it's probably more trouble than its worth. I'd recommend people use django-suit or django-admin-bootstrapped instead, which worked by simply adding them to my `INSTALLED_APPS`.